# Repository + UnitOfWork pattern for entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I was searching the net up and down and I didn't manage to find a suitable design for my application.
I am looking for Repository+UnitOfWork pattern that will manage connections and dispose them automatically when done.

I need to support both web application where each request will have its own UnitOfWork and windows application where each thread will have its own UnitOfWork. I need the patters to dispose automatically the UnitOfWork whrn request/thread is done.
I also would like to support rolback in case of exception.

Right now I use StructureMap so I don't care to continue use it in the suggest answers.

The reason I need Repository pattern is to achieve all the abilities I need to all my entities.
The reason I need UnitOfWork is to allow changes in more then one entity.

I will really appriciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Take a look at this extensive project: http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Alireza Maddah: There are a lot of stuff, I don't know where to begin and where to look for the example.

Comment: Also take a look at the http://silverlightcookbook.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this blog as a really good starting point:

http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article122.aspx

It starts at the VERY beginning, and provides source code at the end for you.  It also uses StructureMap, so it might be somewhat familiar to you.

Comment: I used this just like you and this lead me to where I am now. I have to support both web application and win application. the UnitOfWork.Current.Dispose(); in Application_EndRequest dispose the UnitOfWork for web. But in the win application the UnitOfWork never disposed. This is my problem. This exmple doesn't dispose the UnitOfWork wisely.

Comment: Yes unfortunately like everyone else is saying you need _some_ logic in there to dispose of it yourself.  For me (for example) almost all of my requests come in over WCF, so I'm able to dispose of the context when the WCF session gets disposed.  For other situations I do need to manually call Dispose.  It's just a fact of life! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the NCommon framework.  You can find a blog about it here: http://www.codeinsanity.com/

Comment: NCommon seems to make use of a static `UnitOfWork` class. This class is -in DI terms- implemented as an *Ambient Context*, which is an DI anti-pattern. Because the OP wants to use Dependency Injection, NCommon doesn't seem a good pick. However, it could still be useful for educational purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article last year about writing LINQ enabled repositories that can be faked easily for unit testing and works well with dependency injection. [Here is the article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84). In short the article describes a unit of work that mimics the LINQ to SQL `DataContext` and wraps an `IDataMapper` interface that abstracts the actual O/RM tool. The unit of work contains properties of type `Repository<TEntity>` such as `Repository<Customer>` or `Repository<Order>` and the repository class implements `IQueryable<T>`, which allows you to LINQ over it.

The `IDataMapper` is a simple interface that looks like this:

```
public interface IDataMapper : IDisposable
{
    Repository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class;

    void Save();
}
```

The solution described in the article is designed to be unit test friendly and DI friendly. In fact, the only configuration you need is the following:

```
string northwindConnection = GetConStr("Northwind");

container.RegisterSingle<IUnitOfWorkFactory<NorthwindUnitOfWork>>(
    new LinqToSqlNorthwindUnitOfWorkFactory(northwindConnection));

container.RegisterSingle<IUnitOfWorkFactory<SalesUnitOfWork>>(
    new EntityFrameworkSalesUnitOfWorkFactory());
```

Comment: But in your NorthwindUnitOfWork you defined all your repositores. What if you have more then 30 entities which each entity hass repository? I add tables almost every application update - It will cause a lot of changes in the NorthwindUnitOfWork and it will be huge file. Isn't there any generic solution?

Comment: @Naor: As a matter of fact, the `NorthwindUnitOfWork` is there only for convenience. If you want you can work directly with the `IDataMapper` (and call it `IUnitOfWork` if you want). The `NorthwindUnitOfWork` simply defines a bunch of properties (one per entity) and calls the `IDataMapper.GetRepository<T>` method. I started out with this approach, but this made my application code less clean. You indeed need to change the `NorthwindUnitOfWork` for any entity you add, but how often do you actually add new entities?

Comment: I add entities often.. this is a large scale application that is not done yet. I will look again at your post with the understand that NorthwindUnitOfWork is not importent and that IDataMapper is actually IUnitOfWork.

Comment: @Naor: The advantage of the given approach, is that while takes a fair amount of code to set up,  there is fairly little code that needs to be added when a new entity is added. Yes, you need to add a property in the `NorthwindUnitOfWork` and optionally an `GetById` extension method, but you wont have to add a new repository for that entity, and you won't need extra test classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have unit of work and repositories and you are using StructureMap so where is the problem?

You can simply configure your classes as:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<IUnitOfWork>()
                              .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
                              .Use<EFUnitOfWork>());
```

And you can use dependency injection to pass unit of work to repositories.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't dispose the UnitOfWork when the thread is done.

Comment: None solution will dispose context for you. It is always your responsibility because you know when you don't need it any more.

Comment: So where should I dispose it??

Comment: You must know it! It is not called Unit of work without reason - it represent single business operation / transaction and should not be used for nothing more.