# Repository pattern in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository

i am just a beginner,i was learning repository patterns today and i cam across this line of code,and i am not able to understand this line of code
neways my question is

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    IRepository i1;
    public HomeController()
    {
        i1 = new Repository();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I am using a repository pattern, `IRepository` is the interface and repository is the class that implements the interface!
but I am not able to undestand this piece of code written below
i1=new repository();
can you please explain what this LOC is intended to do??

Comment: You mean you don't understand what the method `public ActionResult Index()` does?

Comment: Do you mean IOC instead of LOC ?

Comment: NO,i mean this LOC

 i1=new repository();

Comment: THIS LINE OF CODE  i1=new repository()

Comment: the line is showing that the home controller is creating a new instance of the repository class. This is so the code can use it to interact with the database. The code above though isn't using Inversion Of Control. Is there another constructor: public HomeController(IRepository repository) ?

Comment: The code works fine,is is alright if we write repository i1=new repository()

Comment: instead of i1=new repository()?

are both the same??

Comment: repository i1=new repository() will create a privately scoped instance of repository what won't be accessible after your constructor ends. i1 = new repository() will create an instance that will be accessible for the lifetime of the class. I suggest you pass the instance of Irepository into your class in the constructor like public HomeController(IRepository repository). You can then test your HomeController and Inject your dependency (in this case your repository) to aid your unit testing. Have a read of the posts below. they will give you a good idea what to do.

Comment: i1 = new repository() will create an instance that will be accessible for the lifetime of the class


can you please explain this line in detail??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you are referring to is showing that the Home Controller is creating a new instance of the repository class. This is so the code can use it to interact with the database. The code above though isn't using Inversion Of Control. Is there another constructor: public HomeController(IRepository repository) ?. I suggest you have a read about the repository pattern. Some good examples are here:

[Repository + UnitOfWork pattern for entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036060/repository-unitofwork-pattern-for-entity-framework)

[Reposity Pattern (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

[Repository Pattern (Code Project)](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/309753/Repository-Pattern-with-Entity-Framework-4-1-and-C)